# Android App to be a default application for completion of sending an outgoing SMS

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I would like the option of choosing a program to complete the sending of a text message with. For example I type a message in the standard messaging app "Hello World" then click the "Send" button, now I want it to ask me which application I want to complete this action with? Is this possible?

If so could anyone share with me how, I have messed around with intent-filters with the action SENDTO, but this did not have the desired result. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the intent filters to select the app to use to send a message (and compose it too). I think what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Hey, I can get my app to come up when composing a message but not if i compose in the Samsung Galaxy S2 messaging app then click the Send button. Attached is the intent code,
`<application>
<activity>            
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>    
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"  />     
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>      
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />  
            </intent-filter>`